# Observable & Observer in Angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am currently working in Angular 8 live project. During the development i have found "observer.next" is used in multiple places Like:
1) In subscibe
2) in Pipe
3) In observable
I just want to know what is the use of Observer.next and can we use this to anywhere.

Comment: Hi! Basically, `observer.next(value)` is used when defining an `Observable` to send the given value to all of the subscribers. Have a look at this docs: https://angular.io/guide/observables. Hope it helps!

Comment: Read here: [Observer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html#instance-method-next) and [Using observables to pass values](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a publisher, you create an Observable instance that defines a subscriber function. This is the function that is executed when a consumer calls the subscribe() method. The subscriber function defines how to obtain or generate values or messages to be published.

`next` - A handler for each delivered value. Called zero or more times after execution starts.

```
const myObservable = of(1, 2, 3);

// Create observer object
const myObserver = {
  next: x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
};

// Execute with the observer object
myObservable.subscribe(myObserver);
// Logs:
// Observer got a next value: 1
// Observer got a next value: 2
// Observer got a next value: 3
// Observer got a complete notification
```

Also check the following links for more clarification

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/rxjs-observables-observers-operators

https://angular.io/guide/observables#basic-usage-and-terms

Answer (score 0):

We use observer to transform promises to observables, look at the example:

```
const somePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...);

function promToObs(): Observable<string> {
  return new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>) => {
    somePromise.then((result) => {
      observer.next(result);
      observer.complete();
    }).catch(err => result.error(err));
  });
}
```